# Runtime configurable verbs based on specification

Tags: c#

I have an application that adheres to multiple specifications that are very similar but require different verbs for identical actions.  For example, one spec says `jump`, while the other might say `hop`.

I'm looking for something like `CultureInfo` (or possibly even `CultureInfo` but I feel that would be bad practice) to define these verbs.  It must be configurable at runtime (spec change shouldn't require a re-compile).

Comment: "jump" and "hop" seem to belong both to the same culture. Using `CultureInfo` you can differentiate different languages, countries, etc., but not arbitrary specifications.

Comment: @Olivier Right, but I want it to act similar to `CultureInfo`, just with specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a xml file in order to store the verbs

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<verbs>
    <verb name="jump", spec="spec1">jump</verb>
    <verb name="jump", spec="spec2">hop</verb>
    <verb name="consume_food", spec="spec1">eat</verb>
    <verb name="consume_food", spec="spec2">feed</verb>
</verbs>
```

or organized by specification

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<specs>
    <spec name="spec1">
        <verb name="jump">jump</verb>
        <verb name="consume_food">eat</verb>
    </spec>
    <spec name="spec2">
        <verb name="jump">hop</verb>
        <verb name="consume_food">feed</verb>
    </spec>
</specs>
```

Or use a different file for every specification

File: spec1.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<verbs>
    <verb name="jump">jump</verb>
    <verb name="consume_food">eat</verb>
</verbs>
```

File: spec2.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<verbs>
    <verb name="jump">hop</verb>
    <verb name="consume_food">feed</verb>
</verbs>
```

Finally, in a separate configuration file, define which specification was selected. It could be a plain text file containing just the name of the specification or it could be another xml file containing different application settings.

Personally I find it handy to use an old style ini-file. It is easy to read and to change, even by no-programmers.

Comment: This is what I'm going to end up doing if the functionality doesn't already exist in C#.  XML will be fine as my users are (or should be) familiar with it.